# Can I track last pull in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, mercurial-extension

I've recently discovered the collapse extension and I love it. I can work and commit often, and when I'm done with my work I can collapse revisions into one logical changeset. One big changeset instead of many small ones makes the history a lot cleaner.

Sometimes I lose track of which revisions I can collapse (you should never collapse a revision that isn't local). Are there any tools to help me track which revisions came from a pull or a different repo? This would also help with rebase.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CollapseExtension

Comment: It's not quite an answer so I'll put it up here, but it looks like Mercurial is going this sort of functionality in the future.  Changesets will have 'liquid' or 'frozen' states and will be liquid when committed and frozen when pushed.  Nothing's finalized yet, but the mercurial-devel mailing list has a lot of possible UIs described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a **local tag** (`hg tag -l -r tip LASTREMOTE`) every time you pull.

But this is a manual process and you can forget to do it. In this case you can use `hg out`.

Comment: I guess I should just use hg out.

Comment: You could automate that with a pre-pull hook: `[hooks]\npre-pull=hg tag -l -r tip LASTREMOTE`